# Postgres update/insert

Tags: postgresql

I have assigned ranks to students based on their marks. There can be students with the same rank as another.
There are 5 grades and each grade can only have a % of students (% value may change each time)
for eg.,
Grade 1: 5%
Grade 2: 15%
Grade 3: 30%
Grade 4: 50%
Grade 5: 0 (no students to be allocated to this grade)
I need to allocate students to grades based on the rank starting with the first(top marks) student in the list until all students have been allocated to a grade using the grade percentages (if we need to split students between grades due to running out of allocated spots put all students of the same rank in the same higher grade - in this case the % might get affected, which is ok)

I have 13 students with ranks as below,

[image]

I tried as below,

```
    UPDATE student_grading
    set st_grade = 
        CASE
       WHEN row_count <= (total_count * (10/100)) THEN 1
       WHEN (row_count > (total_count * (10/100)) and (row_count <= 
      (total_count * (50/100))) THEN 
     END
   FROM  
   (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student_Rank)) AS row_count,
      count(*) as total_count,
      st_student_ID
    FROM student_grading
    ) AS v_student_grading
    WHERE student_grading.st_student_ID = 
     v_student_grading.st_student_ID;
```

but I have to consider that sometimes no students should be allocated to a grade(eg, Grade 5: 0 (no students to be allocated to this grade)).

It is ok if the percentage changes because of moving same rank student to higher grade. Is it possible to first assign students to grades based upon grade%, then check for students with same ranks in different grades and assign them to the higher grade? Can anyone please help with the postgres code for this ?

Comment: With 13 students, each student represents about 7% of the class. Both Rank 1 students should be in the 1st category (or explain why both with same rank have different grade?) So put top 2 in the 5% (just live with the overage), put next two in 15% group (just live with underage) put next 3 or 4 in 30% group (about right) and put 5 or 6 in the 50% group. There will be no perfect match of percentage working with 13 students.

Comment: The problem is not well defined. Once we have to put more than the allocated share in grade 1, it's undefined how to adjust remaining allocations.